# Ruby Rack call: class vs instance method?

Tags: rack, rackup

I'm using [Rack](http://rack.github.io) to build a REST API.

Should `call` be a class or an instance method?

Answer (score 1):

In fact it does not matter.

`#run` from config.ru wants an object which responds to `#call` and that takes one argument.

A class is an object so it can be used as a Rack application.

**BUT**

As your application will evolve you will likely want to inject some dependencies in your application maybe a database connection :

**config.ru** ex :

```
database    = Database.new
application = Application.new(database)
run application
```

Therfore using an instance would be a better choice, it will be easier to maintain and to test.
Most of the times in OOP you should use instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be an instance method.

See: https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/Rack-app-with-uri-and-HTTP-specific-responses